# php session work on localhost but not on vps webserver

Tags: php, apache, session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["counter"])){
echo session_id()." ".$_SESSION["counter"];
$_SESSION["counter"]++;
}
else{
$_SESSION["counter"]=0;
echo "start counter";
}
?>
```

It's just a basic example code for session. It working find of my PC using XAMPP. But it doesn't work at all when I put it in to my vps webserver. The out put only include"start counter" and never changed whatever I refresh the page. I checked php.ini both on XAMPP and vps. variables_order = "GPCS" request_order = "GP" register_globals = Off session.save_handler = files Above configurations are same on XAMPP and vps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be due to the reason that your session expires too fast on another server. Start by making sure you're setting the session variable correctly. It's possible that sessions either aren't enabled or aren't configured correctly in the `php.ini` file on your server.

You can try putting this in front of the file to see any errors. When you see the error you can figure out where you have gone wrong.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you,Problem solved! I use your method and find no enough disk space. Then I find nohup.out is a 8GB file in my system. I delete it. Now the system is working!